# can scapy arping multiple IP's at once

Tags: ping, scapy, arp

Does scapy allow you to arping multiple IP's at once?

I tried *arping(['192.168.192.9','192.168.192.12'])* but got TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

and *arping(('192.168.192.9','192.168.192.12'))*  but got AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug.
In the mean time, you can perform the ARP ping manually

```
ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") / ARP(pdst=["192.168.0.1", ...]), filter="arp and arp[7] = 2", timeout=3)
```